# Revised: Primes of form $p \equiv m \in S \mod x \ $

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic

Refer to this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/390812/regarding-definition-of-cuban-primes) for background.

I was speculating if there was an elegant way to define sequences
[A007645](https://oeis.org/A007645),[A002313](https://oeis.org/A002313),[A045357](https://oeis.org/A045357),[A045407](https://oeis.org/A045407),[A042986](https://oeis.org/A042986),[A045331](https://oeis.org/A045331),
[A045425](https://oeis.org/A045425),[A045374](https://oeis.org/A045374),[A045400](https://oeis.org/A045400),[A045350](https://oeis.org/A045350),[A042988](https://oeis.org/A042988);

Sequences of form: $$A_n = p,\,\,p \equiv x \in S \mod y \in \{3,4,5,6,7\}$$

And after a good while toying with some variables, I found that since all the numbers in the sequences in question are of the form: $$n \equiv m \in S \mod x,\, 2<x <8$$where, for instance $S$ in [A042986](https://oeis.org/A042986) $=\{0, 1, 2, 3\}$. I figured out that if:

$$\left \lfloor{xn \over y}\right \rfloor = \mathbb{P}_k,\,\, 0<n, 1<y<x<8$$
is $true$, then: $$\mathbb{P}_k \equiv m\in S \mod x$$

Examples:

-[A045400](https://oeis.org/A045400):$$p = \left \lfloor{7n\over 4}\right \rfloor,p = \mathbb{P}_k,p\equiv m \in \{0, 1, 3, 5\} \mod 7$$
  -[A045357](https://oeis.org/A045357):$$p = \left \lfloor{5n\over 2}\right \rfloor,p = \mathbb{P}_k,p\equiv m \in \{0, 2\}  \mod 5$$
  -[A045331](https://oeis.org/A045331):$$p = \left \lfloor{6n\over 5}\right \rfloor,p = \mathbb{P}_k,p\equiv m \in \{1,2,3\}  \mod 6$$

So I guess my question is; Are there any theorem(s) based upon this form?

Answer (score 2):

Let $n=ay+r$ with $0\le r<y$, then
$$
f_{x,y}(n)=\left\lfloor \frac{xn}{y} \right\rfloor = xa+\left\lfloor \frac{xr}{y} \right\rfloor
\equiv \left\lfloor \frac{xr}{y} \right\rfloor \pmod{x}
$$
so $\lfloor xn/y\rfloor$ falls into one of the congruence classes in 
$
S = \left\{ \lfloor xr/y \rfloor | 0\le r < y \right\}
$ modulo $x$ and $|S|=y$ when $y<x,\gcd(x,y)=1$.

Furthermore, for any $z=bx+m\equiv m\in S \pmod{x}$ there is an $r\in[0,y)$ for which $\lfloor xr/y\rfloor=m$  by the definition of $S$, then $z=f_{x,y}(by+r)$.

So
$$
f_{7,4}(n)=\lfloor 7n/4 \rfloor \equiv m \in \{0,1,3,5\} \pmod{7} \\
f_{5,2}(n)=\lfloor 5n/2 \rfloor \equiv m \in \{0,2\} \pmod{5} \\
f_{6,5}(n)=\lfloor 6n/5 \rfloor \equiv m \in \{0,1,2,3,4\} \pmod{6}
$$
for any choice of $n$. Taking the subsequence where $f_{x,y}(n)$ is prime gives you the primes in those congruence classes.